# why return -1 has been used in this example?

Tags: c#, guid

```
 static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Guid obj = Guid.NewGuid();

            Console.WriteLine("New Guid is " + obj.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
            return -1;
        }
```

Can anybody tell me why `return -1` has been used here, and what it means?

Comment: Because you can check the return value, if you start this program with another application (batch, powershell, ...)

Comment: Good question (not in the SO-good-question sense, but in the who-the-****-knows sense). Usually a non-zero return value means that whatever command failed, so maybe the author was just playing around. Or they know -1 means something. Or, it's their favorite number. Or, the compiler was throwing an error and this their way to get it to "shut up and compile".

Comment: In this example it means nothing. But usually it says whether the process finished successfully or some error. It is the exit code of the process. `0` means success and non zero indicates an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Main` method can return `void`:

```
static void Main()
{
    //...
}
```

It can also return an `int`:

```
static int Main()
{
    //... 
    return 0;
}
```

If the return value from `Main` is not used, returning void allows for slightly simpler code.
However, returning an `integer` enables the program to communicate **status information** to other programs or scripts that invoke the executable file.
Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx).

Comment: I don't know that, I feel stupid now ! +1

Answer (score 3):

I'm certainly in no position to tell you why -1 was picked, but in general, that return value would be sent out to the calling application. It's called an exit code. They're generally not used these days in applications, since there's really just no use, but back in the day--and, indeed, still in this context--they were used to convey success or failure (or something else) of a console application.

For example, I might write a program that makes a network call, then returns `0` if the call is successful and, random example, `12` if there was no NIC installed. That way, if some other program was utilizing my EXE, it could understand whether the call was successful or not without having to unreliably parse some output stream.

Most modern applications have `static void Main` functions, because this workflow isn't useful in most situations to the end user. We use GUIs now to show off "there was an error during execution." That's not to say they aren't useful in some circumstances, obviously, for the very same reason as they were before, but the result generally isn't captured if you, say, start a program by double-clicking an icon, and thus it gets thrown away in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of main is the exit code of the program. The caller can check it and react on it. On Windows the common pattern is to use 0 if the program succeeded and different positive integers for error conditions.